# Is it typical to have a significant content size reduction from PhoneGap app and built/final version?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, mobile

I've just put a fair amount of effort designing an app for Android/iOS/Microsoft platforms using PhoneGap (Cordova).  I now find that the page size appears to be significantly different between the Android's viewing of the app within the PhoneGap Developer App and the final built application itself as downloaded to the Android.

**Question:  Is this typical or have I failed to set some property correctly?**

- PhoneGap: v5.0.0-0.28.1
- PhoneGap Developer Application: v0.1.8

Excerpt from index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"       ></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" ></script>
<link   type="text/css"         href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="cordova.js"                    ></script>
```

First Screen example (left side is via PhoneGap Developer App, right side was built and downloaded by the Android phone)

[image]

Second Screen example (again, left side is via PhoneGap Developer App)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah well... I heard nothing so I continued to research, finding the fix for this.  I updated...

```
target-densitydpi=device-dpi
```

...to...

```
target-densitydpi=medium-dpi
```

...and that did it.  The Android phone that I just bought apparently has higher resolution than the average phone.